# Migration strangeness

Tags: support, migration

I asked a question on Programmers.SE:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/64052/is-it-better-to-put-more-logic-in-a-for-loop-condition-or-to-use-a-while-loop

Which got migrated to CodeReview.SE:

[Reversing a string](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1586/is-it-better-to-put-more-logic-in-a-for-loop-condition-or-to-use-a-while-loop)

But... the Programmers.SE one no longer is listed as migrated.

What happened?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[It was reopened and unlocked](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/posts/64052/revisions), and the migration history was cleared about a day later. Assumedly, a discussion determined that the question should've stayed on Programmers.

Comment: Hmm.. strange. Wonder if there's a way to migrate the CR answers back to programmers.se.

Comment: @Billy I don't have a lot of hope for a "yes" answer, but I'll make a quick check on your behalf. ♪

Answer (score 0):

I cleared the migration history on the question and reopened it as I assumed, from the tone of the discussions on [Meta Code Review](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267/do-stylistic-questions-belong-here-or-on-programmers-se), that it wasn't wanted over there.

I didn't think any more of it and didn't go back to check on the state of the discussion.

I can reclose the question if you want.

Or if you want ask a Code Review mod to migrate their version back, I'll merge it back in with the original and then after deleting the merged stub on Programmers and migrated stub on Code Review you'll never know it had left.

Comment: Nah - not a problem. Just didn't know how it happened (lol)

Comment: Yes, if you prefer, I'll migrate it back from CR.

Comment: @Billy - if you want the Code Review version migrating back please let a mod know by flagging the question on Code Review.